# MSBuild exclude/include order

Tags: msbuild

I have a task where I select some files, based on extension, but want some folders not being processed. The problem is that seems that the Exclude filter is applied before the Include one so at the end all the files are included.

This is where I select the files:

```
<CreateItem Exclude="**\.svn\**;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\obj\**;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\**;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\My Project\*.*;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Properties\*.*;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Dependencies\*.*;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Installation\**;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Extenders\**\*.*"
Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.ascx;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.aspx;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.css;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.xml;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.xslt;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.js;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.resx;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.rpt;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.gif;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.jpg;
  $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.png;"
```

>

In this case if any of the "Exclude" folders include any file whose extension matches the "Include" list, it will still be included in the final list.

So the question is how can I force that all files from the excluded folders are in fact exclude.

**EDIT**: seems there was another problem in the MsBuild file that caused this to fail. 
It's working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2y3e43x.aspx) you can read that CreateItem task is deprecated. It is suggested to use ItemGroup, because since .net 3.5 you can embed it in targets. In your case, if you want to be sure exclude is run after include, you can write:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <YourItemName Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.ascx;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.aspx;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.css;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.xml;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.xslt;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.js;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.resx;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.rpt;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.gif;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.jpg;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.png;" Exclude="**\.svn\**;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\obj\**;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\bin\**;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\My Project\*.*;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Properties\*.*;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Dependencies\*.*;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Installation\**;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Extenders\**\*.*"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

I know you already sorted it out, but I'm posting it in case someone else got similar problem. ItemGroup is much more helpful if you want to include data from more than one source and in many places in your code.

Comment: You cannot have an ItemGroup element with an Exclude attribute without an Include attribute, so your first sample won't even compile...

Comment: Thanks! I didn't check properly if it will parse, I will be more careful next time. Removed this example to avoid confusing people

Comment: Thanks for the answer even though you didn't have to. You certainly helped me.